# Matlab - out of memory while calling mex-file in the midde of program

Tags: matlab, memory

I am asking this question because I failed to solve it myself and hope someone can give me any suggestion.

My problem is:

my program includes 3 parts:

```
part-1: video encoder, 
part-2: channel coding - also call to a mex-files: complie from C-function "encodeBits.c" to Matlab-mexfile "encodeBits.mexw32", 
part-3: video decoder.
```

I also perform 4 checks:

check 1: **part-1 + part-2** as a whole. it means without channel coding, program works well.

check 2: pseudo an input to part-2, it means **part-2 stays alone**. part-2 works well.

```
part-2 still works well even under this condition:
                possible array:             **632** MB (6.623e+08 bytes) *
                Memory available for all arrays:   **1054** MB (1.105e+09 bytes) **
                Memory used by MATLAB:              653 MB (6.842e+08 bytes)
                Physical Memory (RAM):             2795 MB (2.930e+09 bytes)
```

check 3: **part-1 + part-2 + part-3** as a whole.

```
    memory before part 1 runs:
        Maximum possible array:             877 MB (9.199e+08 bytes) *
        Memory available for all arrays:   1265 MB (1.326e+09 bytes) **
        Memory used by MATLAB:              441 MB (4.628e+08 bytes)
        Physical Memory (RAM):             2795 MB (2.930e+09 bytes)
    memory before part-2 runs, means after part-1 finished:
        Maximum possible array:             **869** MB (9.107e+08 bytes) *
        Memory available for all arrays:   **1270** MB (1.332e+09 bytes) **
        Memory used by MATLAB:              430 MB (4.511e+08 bytes)
        Physical Memory (RAM):             2795 MB (2.930e+09 bytes)
    and it results error right after part-2 starting with error
        Error using encodeBits
        Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

check 4: tried **part-2 alone again** after clear all variable from check 3
        it still results error

```
        Error using encodeBits
        Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

check 5: **close** Matlab window, open Matlab window and run **part-2 alone**
        it works well.

So, I cannot understand why it happens, I tried to search hard but I still cannot solve it.

Comment: Do you know the line of code that is triggering the `Out Of Memory Error?` Can you simplified code that produces the error?

Comment: Thank you for you comment, the code that triggered error is:
Simplified code:
part 1: 
   read an image to a array and generate a bitstream named "source"
part 2:
   coding "source" to much small bit stream name "accumSyndrome"
   accumSyndrome = encodeBits(source, ladderFile);
where: encodeBits is a function which is complied from C encodeBits.c function.
   function: perform channel coding named LDPCA
   input: 1. bitstream (0/1), 2. an array which plays as a parity check matrix
   output: bitstream which is parity bits.
thank you for your help

Comment: On the other hand, I dont understand, why part-2 can work perfectly under low resource as check 2, but part-2 doesn't work under higher resource as check 3. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your check under load failing at/after the mex call, and using clear all not fixing it, it sounds like you have a memory leak in your mex code. If the mexFunction allocates memory and doesn't clear it matlab is unable to clear the space, and so it will remain allocated until you shut matlab.